# JBDC driver not found even though i have added it to the classpath

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I'm having a problem with my dynamic web project. It is my first project and I want to do something fairly simple. I want to print out the data from my database. I use MYSQL and have set up a database. I want to connect by using the following code :

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Set the MIME type for the response message
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      // Get a output writer to write the response message into the network socket
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

      Connection conn = null;
      Statement stmt = null;
      try {
         // Step 1: Create a database "Connection" object
         // For MySQL
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webshop", "root", "admin");  // <<== Check


      } catch (SQLException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

I get the same message as other posts have already mentioned:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webshop
```

I understood from other posts that one must add the connector to the classpath. I have done this by using the *properties* wizard of Eclipse (the IDE I'm using). This did not work! I have added the *mysql-connector-java-5.1.37* to the classpath. I also tried adding it directly to the WEB-INF/lib folder, alas with no success. The last thing I tried, also unsuccessfully, was to add it to the tomcat7 library.

None of the above seems to work. What am I doing wrong? I couldn't find a working suggestion in the other posts.

Comment: Did you try to link the *.JAR under lib/ directly into your project? You should specify that to the eclipse runtime via configuration of the Project properties. A plenty of tutorial online is available, like http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java) to setup the build and/or runtime path.

Comment: Yes, I basically tried putting it under every /lib folder. And if needed added it to the build path via the project properties window. None of them worked.

Comment: Deschamps, have you tried to copy/move the libraries unders '*/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib'? Here, a useful link: http://www.javahotchocolate.com/tutorials/web-jars.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the great tips and help! Most of the options I found here, I had already tried. So to me it seemed like something was wrong for my setup in particular. It was not a general issue.

I have resolved the issue by simple starting over. Delete eclipse, the tomcat server, everything... Afterwards install again all the necessary stuff. This time it worked first try! I added the connector (only) to the /lib of the tomcat server.

I think maybe the issue was that I had multiple connectors somewhere in the project? Anyway, starting over resolved my issue. I know it's not a nice clean fix, but it worked.

Thanks again for the effort and time!

Answer (score 1):

As it pointed out in [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html), you should:

1. Download mysql connector jar file from [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).
2. Put the downloaded jar file into your `lib` folder.
3. Before your code, you should do `load mysql deriver` thing like this:

   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Answer (score 0):

You should use appropriate library. See the instructions [how to install Connector-J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-installing.html).

> You can install the Connector/J package using either the binary or
>   source distribution. The binary distribution provides the easiest
>   method for installation; the source distribution lets you customize
>   your installation further. With either solution, you manually add the
>   Connector/J location to your Java `CLASSPATH`.
>
> If you are developing servlets or JSPs, and your application server is
>   J2EE-compliant, you can put the driver's
>   `mysql-connector-java-version-bin.jar` file in the `WEB-INF/lib`
>   subdirectory of your webapp, as this is a standard location for third
>   party class libraries in J2EE web applications.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested in previous answers:
 - consider adding the driver JAR to your WEB-INF/lib folder
 - alternatively, if you plan to use it in multiple applications, deploy it under tomcat's lib folder - it will be made available to your app's class loader using the parent loader
 - if using JDBC 3 or older, you may call loadClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") in your servlet's init() method, for example

Perhaps a better approach would be to inject a DataSource object bound to your MySql database. Check the @Resource annotation for example